# T-SQL Nested Statement for Filtered Value / Non-Filtered Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nested

Trying to figure out how i might do something like this.

I have to do some math similar to the following:

```
Apples - 5
Oranges - 4
Pears - 6

Apples / Total Fruit
```

Problem is I had to do a nested `SELECT` statement to filter out the specific category. I'm not sure how to structure this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understand, here is the solution..

lets say, your **table name** is `Fruits` which has two columns - `(Fruit, FruitCount)`.
So try something like this..

`Select Fruit, (FruitCount/(select sum(FruitCount) from Fruits)) as RequiredCount from Fruits`

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be more efficient than doing the aggregation on every row.

```
select Fruit, FruitCount / TotalFruit from
Fruits, (select sum(FruitCount) as TotalFruit from Fruits)
```

Note that FruitCount can't be an integer type or it will get rounded to an integer (ie, 0 or 1) when you perform the division.  Otherwise you will have to cast it to a float or some other decimal type.